# How can I remove the contents I create with my button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a follow up to another question, I'm new at JQuery here... I have an assignment to create a simple JQuery to choose a date, type an event and add them to a list with a small red button in front of each item.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        });
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#bta', function () {

        if ($('#datepicker').val() != '' && $('#evento').val() != '' ) {
           $('#caixa').prepend('<p>' + $('#datepicker').val() + '&nbsp;' + $('#evento').val() + '&nbsp;' + '<input type="button" id="apagar" class="apagar" value="apagar"/>' + '</p>');
            $('input').val('');
        }

    });

     $(document).on('click', '#apagar', function () {
       $( "p" ).remove();
       });

      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box">
            Lista de Tarefas:
            <br><br>
            Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> &nbsp; &nbsp;

            Event: <input type="text" id="evento">    <button id="bta" class="bta">+</button>

            <div id="caixa">  </div>
            </body>
        </div>

</html>
```

The problem I have is pretty simple, the red button I create is supposed to erase the full line I created and that particular line only, the problem is that the red button erases every single content I have on the list.

I know it's because they all have the paragraph tag but how do I do it so that the button erases a single line only?

This is the second question I ask today and I usually don't do this but this is due in like 2-3 days but my next few days are unpredictable when it comes to free time so that's why I'm making a second question today...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting all "p", you can delete only nearest "p".

Change this line:

```
   $( "p" ).remove();
```

With this one:

```
   $(this).closest("p").remove();
```

You have here a full example:
http://jsbin.com/gikululofu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Before I give the solution let me point out a small mistake in the script.

You are adding the same id to your dynamic button `apagar` on click of the button `bta`. The existing code will work since you are using event delegation for the dynamic button click events But this is not right way even though it works ( **Never have elements in the DOM with same Id's**) . What I suggest is **use class for your dynamic button** (which you are already doing)  and use this class in your event delegation selector for click event. So the code of your dynamic button should be like below after removing the id..

`<input type="button" class="apagar" value="apagar"/>'`

Now the solution is to use **closest()** feature of Jquery on the clicked element . Since the button is wrapped inside the `p` tag on click of this button let's find the `p` tag using `closest` which will bubble up untill it finds the element and then remove the `p` tag.
So change your script which should remove the `p` tag to below.

`$(document).on('click', '.apagar', function () {  // changed id selector to class 
   $(this).closest( "p" ).remove(); // access particular p tag and remove
});`